# How should I use Nginx for following?

Tags: nginx, single-page-application

I am trying to run my react app using Nginx.
I created build of my app (name: react-app) and placed it over here `/var/www/react-app`.

Then I created a conf file `/etc/nginx/conf.d/react-app.conf`

```
server {
  listen    8081;
  server_name   localhost;

    location / {
      root  /var/www/react-app;
      index index.html index.html;
    }
}
```

There is `include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;` inside `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf`.
Then I ran `nginx` and opened http://localhost:8081/ in the browser, but result is blank.

How can fix this?

Comment: Could You attach errors from dev-tools console if there are any?

Comment: @PatrykFalba Sorry but i dont have it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should not use `index` and add a `try_files`:

```
server {

  listen 8081;
  server_name localhost;

  location / {        
    root /var/www/react-app;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
  }
}
```

Comment: i made changes but still no use, have i missed any step ?

Comment: @m0rem0rem0re open devtools, and what error do you get in the network tab? Feels like it's a permission issue on your server. You should check your nginx error log

Comment: thanks you ! I refreshed and everything is working,  your suggested changes for conf file worked ! Can you further tell me how can i run another app along with this app ? I was refering https://medium.com/@devyashsanghai/hosting-angular-and-react-app-on-a-same-domain-using-nginx-189f96493818 . I want to run React app along with Angular app in Nginx.

Comment: depends what you want, you can try another server on another port, or on another location. So you can have `location /react` and `location /angular`. You should however then also update the baseHref inside your `index.html`. If you have another port, this is not necessary